# Backing up Steam Games+Saved data to Copy cloud storage

Tags: steam, cloud

I am using Xubuntu 14.04. I have Copy cloud storagehttps://www.copy.com/home/, and I would like to backup my games and their saves to cloud storage. Because I (used to) reinstall often I put all items that I would rather not lose on Copy cloud storage, so that when I install Copy on a fresh install, all my files are restored. I would like to include steam games and game saves on my cloud storage (even the game downloads that I have bought through steam). I would like to be able to reinstall Linux and install Copy and have all my files restored, and then be able to configure Steam to use the games from Copy and their saves. I would also like to be able to update steam games that I bought on the steam store even if I reinstall. If that is not possible, I would only like to be able to store my saves on the cloud. In case anybody will ask, I know about the steam cloud storage but I would rather use my own.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I believe steam automatically backs up all your games and saves.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, but I would also like to backup to my own cloud storage as a backup of the backup. I have also heard that the backup does not work on all games.

Comment: @ryekayo check my comment

Comment: If you check this article out, they provide name of some free software. The thing is, I am not sure if the software is available on Ubuntu but it is work a check: http://www.howtogeek.com/167857/4-ways-to-back-up-your-pc-game-saves/

Comment: If you want to get an extra 5GB (total of 20GB) space for both you and me, you could signup using my referral link https://copy.com?r=LIMHHd

Answer (score 0):

1
you can copy the .steam folder to another harddrive or USB/DVD .
if you re-install Ubuntu fully copy it to ~/   & after the re-installation make a startup application ~/.steam/steam.sh to make steam start when you login.
2
you can you backups.
run backups => folder to save => add folder 'select ~/.steam' .